# SQL Server Pivoting data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written the following SQL Statement (SQLServer 2012)

```
select distinct ResponseId,piv.Address_Risk_Line1 , piv.Buildings_Cover,
piv.Policy_Cover, piv.Policy_JointCover from [dbo].[UDL_Answers] 
pivot  ( max(Answer) FOR Question in ([Address_Risk_Line1], [Buildings_Cover],
[Policy_Cover], [Policy_JointCover]) ) as piv
```

my output returned comes in the form:

```
ResponseId  Address_Risk_Line1  Buildings_Cover Policy_Cover    Policy_JointCover
1           NULL                NULL            NULL            NULL
1           NULL                NULL            NULL            false
1           NULL                NULL            Combined        NULL
1           NULL                true            NULL            NULL
1                               NULL            NULL            NULL
```

What I really want is all of the above on a single line can anyone show me how I can do this

Comment: Provide sample data / also *SQLFiddle* would be nice.

Comment: @ Stanislovas Kalašnikovas I have provided sample data. I've given my statement and the output that I get so far.

Comment: You haven't provided sample data, just output and query.

Comment: @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas NO this is the output I am currently getting. my desired output is to have all of this on a single line. since all the lines have the same ResponseId).

Comment: I'm asked for sample data to see how table looks like before pivoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running into issues with NULL's in your data.  This is an excellent reference for pivot: [Questions about Pivot](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-pivoting-data-in-sql-server-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/) Look at the example where it states "grouping is based on all columns not specified in the PIVOT clause" and you will see similar results as well as a solution.

Comment: I didn't see the exact answer here, but it sent me on my way. I have changed my SQL to be: select * from(
select ResponseId, Question,Answer from dbo.udl_answers) as QnA
pivot(max(Answer) for Question in ([Address_Risk_Line1], [Buildings_Cover],[Policy_Cover], [Policy_JointCover]) ) as piv